# Place text at bottom of div/td, when using precent height

Tags: html, slideshow, vertical-alignment

http://jsfiddle.net/rZGw9/

I have tried a lot of things, and basically never been close to the answer. I have a box that actually works (with the same code!), but with 3 pages and slide-script between them. So why isn't it working in the example over? I am sure it is really simple!

---

The slide page script if anyone is intrested: (got it from StackOverflow I think, but can find the link... Sorry)

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function(){
    $("#site_link").cycle({
        fx : "scrollHorz",
        next : ".next a",
        prev : ".prev a",
        startingSlide : 1,
        timeout : 0
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering myself here.

Adding `position:relative` to `#contain` did the trick.